# How to make my check box start with true?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using boostrapvue and my checked box default false, is there away i can use the props to make my app show a default true?

```
<b-form-checkbox v-model="checked" autofocus="true" 
      name="AddVendcheck-button"  value="true" switch="true">
            </b-form-checkbox>
```

this is a simple question and might get down voted.. but i didnt see any similar question on bootstrap. You can see, i try true on all the props and it is still coming as false..

Comment: Prop for checkbox is "checked". So you would need to do "checked='true' "

Comment: tried that and it didnt work

Comment: `v-model` means it has two-way data binding. Is the data property `checked` initialized to `true`?

Comment: Andrew I am new to coding. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Oh,this is is vue-bootstrap. I don't know Vuejs, but I briefly read the doc and it's pretty simple. Keyword should be "v-model". Look it up

Comment: basically in your vue component you are binding the boolean value of the checkbox to a [data property](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#data-properties) "checked".. Unless you in initialize it, it will be undefined which is falsy in JS. So you need to initialize it to true. In the docs `count` is initialized to `4`, just replace `count` with `checked` and `4` with `true`. Post what code you have and I can show you in your code what to do.

Comment: Andrew i think that is the answer but i need your help.. I am using an arrow function from data.. how do incorporate the return

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231809/boostrapvuejs can you give me 5 mins of your time here

Answer (score 0):

you should bind the `checked` value to a `data` property in your script and make this input reactive. I think you should try improve your understanding of `vue js` for a better understanding of `bootstrap-vue`.

Here is the code snippet that solves your issue.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      checked: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle_checkbox() {
      this.checked = !this.checked
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-checkbox v-model="checked" switch="true" />
  <b-button @click="toggle_checkbox()">Toggle</b-button>
</div>
```